# tymeleaf checkbox without binding to an object or entity

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

i need to use check box to fire off a java if statement without having to bind the check box to any entity or object here is what i need in code

```
 <input type="checkbox" th:field="${deleteImages}" th:checked="*{false}">Delete all images</input>
```

the controller would be this

```
public String updateProduct(@ModelAttribute("product") Product product,
                                @ModelAttribute("deleteImages") Boolean deleteImages) {

if (deleteImages) {
                imageService.deleteImages(savedProduct.getId());
            }
```

i can not figure out how to fix this checkbox.. i don't need it tied up to any object just return true when clicked and false when unchecked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this without binding it to an object, just use RequestParams.  Like this:

Form:

```
<form method="POST" class="action-buttons-fixed">
  <input type="checkbox" name="deleteImages" />
  <button>Go</button>
</form>
```

Java:

```
@PostMapping("/whatever")
public String updateProduct(@RequestParam(required = false, defaultValue = "false") boolean deleteImages) {
  if (deleteImages) {
      imageService.deleteImages(savedProduct.getId());
  }
}
```

You can't, however, mix bound and unbound properties on the same form.  If you want to do that, you should just create a new `Form` object that contains the both the product and the deleteImages variable.

```
class Form {
    private Product product;
    private boolean deleteImages;
}
```

And then change your form bindings appropriately.